# ListJS - Count item after search

Tags: javascript, fuzzy-search, listjs

How to count item after search by input field on ListJS?

I don't know where I can get it, because I just use basic example :

```
var params = {
  valueNames : ['titleList', 'currentList', 'typeCode', 'categoryCode'],
  plugins: [ ListFuzzySearch() ]
}

var searchSightseeing = new List('sightseeingList', params);
```

I have try use method `size()` in `oninput` my field like this :

```
$('#sightseeing-name').on('input', function(){
  console.log(searchSightseeing.size());
})
```

But it still result count of all item.

Comment: please share your html also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long-long research, I have get an answer.

to get update on input change use method `keyup`.

add `searchSightseeing.update().matchingItems.length` to get count.

```
var params = {
  valueNames : ['titleList', 'currentList', 'typeCode', 'categoryCode'],
  plugins: [ ListFuzzySearch() ]
}

var searchSightseeing = new List('sightseeingList', params);

searchSightseeing.on('searchComplete', function(){
  console.log(searchSightseeing.update().matchingItems.length);
});
```